# GnuPG / OpenPGP: How to eliminate redundancy in PGP private key?

Tags: key-management, pgp, rsa, obfuscation, gnupg

I examined a few randomly generated private keys generated by Gnu PG, and found a lot of redundancy.

1. It is enclosed by `-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----` and `-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----`
2. There is a CRC checksum at the end (e.g., `=WXYZ`)
3. All RSA keys that I generated start with "lQ"

I tried removing the checksum and the importing works. Also, removing the BEGIN/END markers and the common "lQ" prefix seems reversible. I am wondering how much further can I go to make the key less redundant and more obfuscated?

My main security concern is:

If the attacker steals the *encrypted* private key, he can (more) quickly and easily verify that the decryption succeeded (in the case above, by verifying it begins with "lQ" and that the checksum is right).

*Note*: I used the `gpg -a --export-secret-key`, but it looks the non-ASCII encodeded key (no `-a`) has pretty much the same redundancy (I verified this using a hex editor).

Is there a specification / standard that specifies which parts of the private keys are "truly secret", and which one serve as a descriptor, checksum and can be safely removed (provided that I trust trust the key is unmodified)?

Answer (score 1):

OpenPGP is defined in [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), which probably is the specification you're looking for. OpenPGP files (no matter whether binary or ASCII-armored) are composed of individual packets, each having a header (that is probably what you have been observing regarding the "IQ").

In an OpenPGP secret key packet, quite a lot of meta data is stored. As it also contains the public key, expect the user ID packets to be included - if these are the same, there will be more redundancy.

For working out the parts not specific to RSA keys of given size, better work with binary files instead of ASCII-armored ones (you're closer to the values given in the specifications). Very helpful at dissecting OpenPGP files will be `gpg --list-packets`, which dumps the contents of each packet in a more human-readable version, but also gives you packet identifiers and similar data you can look for in a hex editor.